# Making a chat app with a java client and php server

Tags: java, php, android, chat

I need to send messages between two Android's running my app, with a PHP server in between. Devices are identified by phone number, but I have no clue how to send the message

I've looked into sockets and the sorts but do not really know how to work it with PHP
Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713792/making-android-chat-application-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the idea of RESTful apis, [here is a start](http://www.restapitutorial.com/). Essentially what you do it have different urls that the android app can send data to. Sending data to one might make a chat between two androids and return the chat id. Then you can send data to another to send a chat message, including that chat id. The only thing you want to be careful of is security. A general rule when making a api like this is, asume people will find these urls, and asume people will use these malicously. So incorperate some sort of security, look at how other peeople do it, like Google.
Another important concept in RESTful apis is the idea of http verbs. In http you can commonely, GET(What your browser does most of the time), POST, PUT, and DELETE. This allows you to have 1 url and many actions, like so

```
GET /users/chats - returns users chats  
POST /users/chats - creates a chat  
PUT /users/chats - updates a chat  
DELETE /users/chats - deletes a chat
```

**Security**
Generally when I create a RESTful api I use a token secret combination. For anyone to use my API they have to send a token with it, along with a secret. If the token they send and the secret match, then they can use the api.